# ODP.NET managed driver does not return contol in case of command timeout

Tags: oracle, odp.net, managed

I am using ODP.NET managed driver 12.1.0.2.1 (ODAC 12c Release 3) and have found critical bug. In case of timeout during command execution lead to lost of threads and connections from connection pool.

This test always fails:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException))]
[Timeout(70000)]
public void OracleCommandTimeoutTest()
{
    const string connectionString =
        "user id=user;password=pass;data source=192.168.1.1:1521\db";
    using (var connection = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // we need for 60 seconds timeout
        command.CommandTimeout = 60; //default value is 0 (unlimited)
        //here can be any query that takes longer time than specified in CommandTimeout
        command.CommandText = "execute DBMS_LOCK.sleep(70)";
        connection.Open();
        //this statement will never return control
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //BUG:connection and command never be disposed and test will be fail after timeout
    }
}
```

Let's look inside driver. Find function:

```
internal void ReceiveExecuteResponse
```

The function handles exception (ORA 03111) and call Reset() here:

```
catch (NetworkException ex)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode != 3111)
        throw;
    else
        this.m_marshallingEngine.m_oracleCommunication.Reset();
}
```

after sending URG packet to Oracle database and reads answer fuction goes to loop that never ends here:

```
while (!flag1)
    {
```

Function tries to read response stream until AppDomain will be unloaded.
We can't use managed driver until this bug will be fixed. Unmanaged x64 driver passes this test succesfully.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be reported to an Oracle corporate site.

Comment: Ivan, if thread is locked, please repost here: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=146

Comment: Ivan, this is invalid SQL: command.CommandText = "execute DBMS_LOCK.sleep(70)"; Are you sure you are using ODP.NET (Oracle.DataAccess.Client or Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client) and not accidentally using MS OracleClient?

Comment: Christian, I have used another query like "select count(*) from abc.table".

Comment: Bob, I think it can be useful information for many developers. I'm in process of creating official bug report to Oracle.

Comment: @Bob - I agree with Ivan.  If there is issue with Ivan already putting forth the effort to suspect this is a bug, I would have him simply reword to "why does it do this" and then he can assert that it was a bug in a self-answered manner after getting an answer from Oracle.

Comment: @IvanKarmanov Did you get a response from Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

It seems clear that the OP accidentally used MS OracleClient. It does work with ODP.NET.

Working example:

```
public static void OracleCommandTimeoutTest()
{
  System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
  try
  {
    const string connectionString = @"user id=scott;password=tiger;data source=inst1";
    using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
      // we need for 60 seconds timeout
      command.CommandTimeout = 20; //default value is 0 (unlimited)

      //here can be any query that takes longer time than specified in CommandTimeout
      command.CommandText = "BEGIN DBMS_LOCK.sleep(70); END;";
      connection.Open();

      //this statement will never return control
      sw.Start();
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      sw.Stop();

      Console.WriteLine("ExecuteNonQuery Completed (Didn't timeout): " + sw.Elapsed + " ms");
      //BUG:connection and command never be disposed and test will be fail after timeout
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Timed-Out after: " + sw.Elapsed + " ms");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

The above test case gives the following result:

Timed-Out after: 00:00:21.0581601 ms
ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

Comment: Christian,
It seems to me that you use unmanaged Oracle Client. It passes this test. I've added to my test full namespaces to be much clear.

Comment: No, I used ODP.NET managed provider. I cannot reproduce this. I thought you might be using MS OracleClient because you used the "execute" syntax which is specific to their provider.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your ODP.NET client to 4.121.1.0 or higher. It looks like the `CommandTimeout` didn't work in your ODP.NET version. I just ran Christian's test on 4.121.1.0 and it just works. I tried all Execute* operations and `CommandTimeout` works for all of them.